# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class - composer

Tags: php, pdo, composer, namespace, php-autoload

Em alguns posts(perguntas), não consegui encontrar uma solução para este erro e gostaria da ajuda de vocês expert no assunto.
É algo simples, só quero que mostre um simples echo "Listar Pagina" de acordo com o composer.json, para ter certeza de que esta tudo ok no trajeto, mas, nada resolve, não encontro o erro... :'(

**index.php**

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use Core\ConfigController as Home;

$Url = new Home();
$Url->carregar();
```

**ConfigController.php**

```
<?php
namespace Core;
class ConfigController {
    public function carregar() {
        $listarPg = new \App\adm\Models\AdmsPaginas();
    }
}
```

**AdmsPaginas.php**

```
<?php
class AdmsPaginas {
    public function listarPaginas() {
        echo "Listar Paginas";
    }
}
```

**autoload.php**

```
{
    "name": "w/m",
    "description": "Projeto WM",
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "WM",
            "email": "wm@gmail.com"
        }
    ],
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Core\\": "core",
            "Sts\\": "app/sts",
            "Adm\\": "app/adm"
        }
    },
    "require": {}
}
```

**autoload_psr4.php**

```
<?php

// autoload_psr4.php @generated by Composer

$vendorDir = dirname(__DIR__);
$baseDir = dirname($vendorDir);

return array(
    'Sts\\' => array($baseDir . '/app/sts'),
    'Core\\' => array($baseDir . '/core'),
    'Adm\\' => array($baseDir . '/app/adm'),
);
```

[**Pastas**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/opS5W.jpg)

**[Erro](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vh5Sz.jpg)**

Comment: Evite agradecer e cumprimentar nas publicações pois aqui no [pt.so] são considerados ruído de comunicação. Veja [Que tipo de comportamento é esperado dos usuários?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/behavior), [Saudações e Agradecimentos](http://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/846/137387) e [Como se portar ao perguntar/responder?](http://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/38/137387).

Answer (score -2):

Obrigado, já resolvi, só precisei colocar o caminho no index.php

**index.php**

```
<?php

require './core/Config.php';
require './vendor/autoload.php';
require './app/adm/Models/AdmsPaginas.php';


use Core\ConfigController as Home;

$Url = new Home();
$Url->carregar();
```